# error in pulling trace file -sdcard

Tags: android

Can anybody help me out with traceview!
I created sdcard and mounted it on my emulator , after closing my app , when i try to pull to copy the files (using command:adb pull /sdcard/calc.trace /tmp)i get this error:"remote object /sdcard/calc.trace does not exist".I am listin gdown the commands in sequence.
1)f:>mksdcard 1024 ./myimage
2)f:>emulator -sdcard ./myimage -avd 1
3)(After running my app and exiting the app)adb pull /sdcard/calc.trace /tmp

in my activity i have start/stop method tracing with fiename calc.trace.
n ya i am running windows -->"\"
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this can help somebody with a ||ar pbm.
http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/02/tutorial-how-to-emulate-sd-card-with.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html

Regards